# How to create multiple textboxes based on combobox selected value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, textbox

Here's what I want:

From combobox you select the size of table n x m (max 10x10) and next you get that many of textboxes able to fill with data.

I started to do it with hidden 10x10 and I used code like:

```
if (ComboBox1.Text.Comntains("3") = true)
{
 TextBox1.Visibility = true;
 TextBox1.Visibility = true;
 TextBox1.Visibility = true;
}
```

but it's not a solution as I need 10x10.

Maybe the solution is simple, but I have just started with c#.

edit:

I tried to debug my program, and the problem is when I run, I can set value of the comboboxes and click 'OK' button. I want to generate the textboxes after clicking 'OK'. After that, error appear: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in simplex_method.exe.
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

And tip is to check if the object is 'null' before calling the method.

code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int verticalCount = 0;
        int horizontalValue = 0;

        verticalCount = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        horizontalValue = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;

        for(var i = 0; i < verticalCount; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < horizontalValue; j++)
            {
                var newTextBox = new TextBox();

                var x = 10 * verticalCount;
                var y = 10 * horizontalValue;

                newTextBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

                this.Controls.Add(newTextBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code is 2 comboboxes and some initialize conditions (sizeable form).

Comment: Do you really need textboxes? Why do not use table?

Comment: I need windows application and I need user to fill the boxes with data. Next I will use the data to make some calculations.

Comment: Are you using WinForms?

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows Forms

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: Kind of. We have project done in Console Application and now I wanted to create windows application of it. It's my first project in c#

Comment: I need to know what you have right now to know how help you.

Comment: I edited the topic. Don't know how to check if object is not null before calling the method, I've read something about initialize by using 'new' but I already have it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
// read values from comboboxes (10 is default value)
var verticalCount = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedValue ?? 10);
var horizontalValue = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.SelectedValue ?? 10);

// create m*n textboxes
for(var i = 0; i < verticalCount; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < horizontalValue; j++)
    {
        var newTextBox = new TextBox()
        {
            Name = string.Format("TextBox_{0}_{1}", i, j); // put the name here
        }
        var x = //calculate x location for textbox
        var y = //calculate y location for textbox
        newTextBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

        // add new created textbox to parent control (form)
        this.Controls.Add(newTextBox)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object” when I try to run my code

Comment: Well, I don't have all your code. On which row you got this error? Can you add more details in your question?

Comment: It stopped on line: var verticalCount = (int)ComboBox1.SelectedValue;. I think I need to check if the object is not null. But I'm not sure how to do it, I create new object by 'new'...

Comment: I edited a bit the code and added checking if there is a selected value, and if there isn't then you default value = 10.

Comment: After applying diferences, program is running, but it only appear 1 textbox, no matter if I change default value of combobox or the position of textboxes.

Comment: Have you debugged this code? What values `verticalCount` and `horizontalValue` are?

Comment: Incrementation insinde two loopes are good, but the 'verticalCount' and 'horizontalValue' are not changing and value is set to default '?? 10' in every loop. Maybe there is more textboxes in window application but they are right on top of each other?

Comment: You're right. in your code in the row `var x = 10 * verticalCount;` you need to multiply not to the verticalCount but for `i` (and `j` instead of `horizontalValue`).

Comment: It worked now :) But I still can't get selected value from combobox, function draw me only deafult value, I can't set it using combobox. Maybe I need to set it earlier than when button clicked?

Comment: probably, the problem in how do you initialize your comboboxes. if your comboboxes have only texts and each item has no value, then you need to use `SelectedText` instead of `SelectedValue`.